# How long did it take to run an Observable using RxJava (ReactiveX)?

Tags: java, scala, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm using java ReactiveX (RxJava) in scala Play Framework 2.5 to communicate with couchbase asynchronously I would like to know how long it took for my observable to run? I define my observable using the code below.

```
def get(id: String) : Observable[Profile] = {
  this.bucket
    .async()
    // can I have a start time here possibly using map?
    .get(id)
    .map[Profile](toProfile)
    // can I have an end time here possibly using map?
}
```

I call it using the following

```
Thread.sleep(1000)

val observable = get("myID")

Thread.sleep(1000)

// measure start time here
println("observable: " + observable.toBlocking.first())
// measure end time here

Thread.sleep(1000)
```

How can I measure how long it took for the observable to run?

Thanking you in advance

Francis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to start your timer in a `doOnSubscribe()` block and then complete it in the `onTerminated()`.

An example might be something like:

```
long start;
observable()
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> start = System.nanoTime())
    .doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start));
```

Alternatively you could follow what Netflix do with RxNetty and return the start time as part of the object flowing through the chain and use that at the end.